# Linux: Error Code for Sendmail not Found

Tags: c++, linux, sendmail

i deployed following C++ Code on a Linux System

```
int sendEMail ( string sEMailAddress, string sEMailSubject , string sEMailText )
{

int nRc = nOK;
    // send email here
    const int nBUFFERSIZE = 55000;
    static char szCommand [ nBUFFERSIZE ] = { 0 };
    const char * szEmailText = NULL;


    FILE *fpipe = popen("sendmail -t", "w");

    szEmailText=sEMailText.c_str();

    if ( fpipe != NULL )
    {
        fprintf(fpipe, "To: %s\n", sEMailAddress.c_str());
        fprintf(fpipe, "From: %s\n", "test@mail.de");
        fprintf(fpipe, "Subject: %s\n\n", sEMailSubject.c_str());
        fwrite(sEMailText.c_str(), 1, strlen(sEMailText.c_str()), fpipe);
        pclose(fpipe);
    }
    else
    {
        Logger_log ( 1 , "ERROR: Cannot create pipe to mailx" );
                nRc = -1;

    }
    return nRc;
}
```

This Code works fine. I have to ensure that sendmail should be found on System. Because i got a Problem. PATH Variable was not set correct. Therefore sendmail could not be found on System. There was no Error Message, which i received. Email seems to send out. But it was not. How can I realize within Code (return or Error Code), that I receive a Error Message, if Sendmail Process could not be found?
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**One way(to specifically check for command not found error)**:

`2(stderr)` is a default file descriptor on linux system.

redirect this error to file **errorfile**. Now compare the contents of **errorfile** and if the content has `command not found` string, this would ensure that command was not found.

```
FILE* fpipe = popen("sendmail 2>errorfile", "w");

FILE* file = fopen("complete path to errorfile", "r");

char buf[124];

fgets(buf, 100, file);

printf("%s", buf);

if(strstr(buf, "command not found")!=NULL)
  printf("Command not found");
```

**Other way**,

`system` function can be used

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;
i = system("sendmail");
printf("The return value is %d", i);
```

This return value can be used to check whether command executed successfully or not. The return value is your machine os dependent, so check whatever is the return value. However it is usually zero for success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think from the manual there are some answers:
1. popen calls /bin/sh -c <your command> so I guess popen will always succeed unless /bin/sh is not found
2. you should check the return code:

```
int ret_code=pclose(fpipe);
if (ret_code != 0)
{
    // Error handling comes here
}
```

From Manual Page (man popen)

> The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by wait4(2).

...

> The pclose() function returns -1 if wait4(2) returns an error, or some other error is detected.